# HDD password cracking

Tags: exploit, disk-encryption, password-cracking, decryption

I recently changed the decryption key to my WD My Passport HDD two days ago. Before I left for the weekend, I tested to make sure that the key would work. However, the password that I set, which got from the pseudo-random key generator,  does not work anymore. I copy/pasted the password into the field to change it, and I always make sure that I have copied the correct item before confirming the change. That all said, there exists a possibility I hit a key while trying to copy the password and did not notice, so I hopefully know the 95% of the password.

Are there any tools available to crack external hdd in a scenario like mine?

Edit: I used WD's Drive Unlock full disk encryption

Comment: What disk encryption software are you using? The tools would have to be specific to that. Also, what kind of $*#& encryption software doesn't ask you to type a new password twice to prevent this kind of thing?

Comment: That would have been helpful to include... I used WD proprietary Drive Unlock. Which is not the best, and I do plan on using something different after this is resolved. When one resets the password it does have you enter it in twice, but I could have "fat fingered" something to the end of the password without noticing and then pasted into both fields. This is the first time that I have successfully saved the incorrect password.

Comment: Drive unlocker is universal and as the name suggests, does not actually do the locking. With a typenumber or photo of the crypto chip, we could try to see if the drive is vulnerable to one of the following recent published attacks against WD drives http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2015/Oct/79

Comment: How many chars does your saved password have ? Only alphanumerical or specials too ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the software doesn't have a power-up limited number of tries, you could script the GUI interactions with sikuli.

http://www.sikuli.org/

Don't expect hundreds of tries per second.  I would expect less than 10 tries per second... but that could very well be enough.